# In Swing, how to apply KeyListener on no specific component

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

Generally we apply the Key Listener on specific components like text field, password fields, etc. But I would like to generalize this listener behavior to be applicable to all.

Comment: You may also want to have a look at [key bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Comment: no, generally, we do not use KeyListener at all ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Swing was designed to be used with Key Bindings which might do what you want. I would start by checking out [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/). Don't forget to read the Swing tutorial for complete information.

If that doesn't help then see [Global Event Listeners](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/) for a couple of suggestions.

Comment: Consider my requirement is like this - I wrote a system tray app. That is by default minimized to system tray. Now I open notepad and type something. I would like to capture this key press events. Is this possible?

Comment: I'll get back to you in 4 months.

Answer (score 1):

All swing components are a JComponent. You may use all of then as a JComponent:

```
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
   JComponent component = (JComponent) e.getSource();
   // TODO Implements your action
}
```

You can see that this is a limited approach.

You also may work according to the class of your source:

```
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    Object source = (JComponent) e.getSource();

    if (source instanceof JTextField) {
        // TODO Implment action for JTextField
    } else if (source instanceof JTextArea) {
        // TODO Implment action for JTextArea
    }
}
```

Depending on your needs you may use the Reflections API to do this...

Comment: please read the api doc (hint: InputEvent has a method to obtain a narrower source type than Object ...)

Comment: @Eldius Consider my requirement is like this - I wrote a system tray app. That is by default minimized to system tray. Now I open notepad and type something. I would like to capture this key press events. Is this possible ?